# Android studio Error about v-26 and v-17

Tags: android, android-studio

Frankly I miss my original source. so I decompile my .apk, then I'm fixing it.

and I solve many part but I don't know how to solve this error..

please give me any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: "AAPT2 error: check logs for details": did you do that? Was some useful information in the logs?

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I added about AAPT error. but still have error about keyboardNavigationCluster things..